# how to understand the shallow copy

Tags: shallow-copy

```
public class noorderedlist {
        node head;  
  public void afadd(int element){
        node newnode=new node(element);
        if(head==null){
            head=newnode;
            return; 
            }
            node temp=head;
    while(temp.next != null){
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            temp.next = newnode;
        }
  public void print(){
        node currentnode=head;
        while(currentnode!=null){
            System.out.print(currentnode.element);
            currentnode=currentnode.next;
        }
public class node {
    node next=null;
    int element;
    public node(int element){
        this.element=element;
    }
```

i want to write method to add point in a single link list,it works but i have a problem.why the  head will change after the change of the temp?i hear about that is the shallow copy,but why the shallow copy does not work in"temp=temp.next"?,according to that in the loop the temp is changing then the head should change like "head=temp.next", but when i execute the print method the element of the head does not change but it adds a new point in the end of the link list. so what's going on here?

Comment: Can you tell us what language this is? It looks like Java. Besides some missing closing brackets, the code posted seems to work just fine. Can you also post code how you use these classes that exhibit the wrong behavior?

Comment: Thanks,i have solved this problem by myself